# Is there a way to hide all of the HUD when watching replays?

Tags: starcraft-2

I already know that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> will hide the bottom part of the HUD.

But how can I hide the rest of the HUD that is shown on the top of the screen and the replay progress bar?

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much for actually posting the question. I think you're the first person to do that. <3

Comment: I doubt you can remove the player controls as every caster seems to hide it behind an overlay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see that is not posible, here is a list of what you can do while watching a replay:

> Unit Following - You can lock the camera to any unit to follow it
>   around the map. To do this select the unit and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +
>   <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.
>
> Replay Overlay - An overlay in the top left displays various
>   information for every player as chosen by the viewer. These options
>   are listed below.
>
> - **N**one - Closes the box.
> - **R**esources - Displays Mineral, Gas and Supply counters.
> - **I**ncome - Displays resource mining over a set period of time and the number of workers.
> - **S**pending - Displays where resources are being spent, either on Economy, Technology or Army.
> - **U**nits - Displays number of units.
> - Units **L**ost - Displays number of lost units.
> - Pro**d**uction - Displays all research, construction and production taking place.
> - **A**rmy - Displays Army units in terms of resource cost and total Supply stats.
> - AP**M** - Displays average and current APM. Due to Game Speed issues, these are currently inaccurate.
>
> Patch 1.3.0 introduced several new features and Patch 1.3.3 changed
>   the Current APM hotkey. These are listed below:
>
> - In a 1v1 game, both players’ resource rows are shown in the upper right at the same time.
> - The main game UI can now be hidden/shown by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>.
> - The ability to toggle between player unit colors and team unit colors when watching a replay or observing by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.
> - New bigger panels are now available when observing or viewing a replay of 1v1 games. These panels are large and are shown in the top
>     center portion of the screen:
>
>   - Player Name Panel: Displays the players' name, team color, race, and supply count - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>.
>   - Current Income: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.
>   - Army and Worker supply: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.
>   - Units and Workers killed: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.
>   - Current APM: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.
>
> **Tips**
>
> - If you've lost a key unit in a game, for example the blue player's [[Banshee]], you may be able to find it by selecting a blue unit and
>     finding it on the control group display. Just double click the control
>     group the Banshee is in and the camera will focus on the units.
> - By holding <kbd>V</kbd> when having a unit of one player selected your vision will switch to that of the player until you release
>     <kbd>V</kbd>.

Source: [Liquipedia](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Replay_Features)

Comment: It would be nice if you would insert some/all of the points here, just in case the site goes down (which I dont hope for TL ^-^)

Comment: @F.S. is that better ;D

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can with the letter <kbd>H</kbd>.